# How to view Android/data/your.package.name files on external storage in Android 4.2 with the multi user environment?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Android 4.2 added multi user support for tablets. Now when you request a path to save files on external storage via a method like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` you get a value like: `/storage/emulated/#/Android/data/your.package.name/` The # being a number depending on what user you are currently logged in as.

This works fine but I have noticed that DDMS's File Explorer and also the [Android File Transfer](http://www.android.com/filetransfer/) are not able to see these files.

DDMS's File Explorer cannot see anything past `storage/emulated/` except an empty `legacy` folder. File Transfer can see the /Android/data/ folder but for an app running as debug, its files are not visible (but they do exist).

Is there any way to get DDMS or File Transfer to work with these devices? (Hopefully without having to root the device...)

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aha!

Try `/mnt/shell/emulated/N`, for various values of `N` like `0`. That seems to map properly on my Nexus 10 and my Galaxy Nexus in DDMS. I cannot comment on the File Transfer tool, though.

BTW, the numbers are not sequential for the users. So on my N10, the original user is `0`, the second user is `10`.

Comment: YES! Thank you. You are like a magical wizard that travels around here and fixes things for people. Thanks again.

Comment: Like you said this works in the File Explorer (DDMS) but not in the File Transfer tool. I can live with this!

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty: Thanks! And you are like a, um, small, er, cuddly, uh, young cat! :-)

Answer (score 3):

As Jelly Bean 4.2 supports multi-user profiles, the sd-card browsing has been changed a bit.

You must have **ADT v 21** or higher to browse emulated sd-card. 
**/mnt/shell/emulated/0** is for default user. See the image attached for more detail.[image]

[Enlarge Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDdcW.png)